# Nice RSync on remote

Tags: rsync, remote

Is there a way to `nice` the RSync deamon on the destination machine? I have to rsync a huge chuck of data including many small files and am afraid that the remote RSync client will significantly slow down the destination.

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 box I have the following text in /etc/default/rsync:

```
# run rsyncd at a nice level?
#  the rsync daemon can impact performance due to much I/O and CPU usage,
#  so you may want to run it at a nicer priority than the default priority.
#  Allowed values are 0 - 19 inclusive; 10 is a reasonable value.
RSYNC_NICE=''

# run rsyncd with ionice?
#  "ionice" does for IO load what "nice" does for CPU load.
#  As rsync is often used for backups which aren't all that time-critical,
#  reducing the rsync IO priority will benefit the rest of the system.
#  See the manpage for ionice for allowed options.
#  -c3 is recommended, this will run rsync IO at "idle" priority. Uncomment
#  the next line to activate this.
# RSYNC_IONICE='-c3'
```

In theory, by setting these values to 10 and -c3 respectively then restarting the rsync daemon it should run the daemon at the requested nice levels.  However, upon doing this I found it was still running at a nice level of 0.

```
$ ps -lfp $(pidof rsync)
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root     18704     1  0  80   0 -  2785 poll_s 13:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

So what's going on here?  I looked at the systemd unit file for rsync and found this:

```
$ cat /lib/systemd/system/rsync.service 
[Unit]
Description=fast remote file copy program daemon
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rsyncd.conf

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It's not even looking at my /etc/default/rsync file. This file is only used if you are using the System-V init-System. For systemd (which is the default since Debian 8/jessie, it is ignored.

As the /lib/systemd/system/rsync.service file can get overwritten copy it to /etc/systemd/system/rsync.service. Then change the ExecStart line to look like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nice -n 10 /usr/bin/ionice -c3 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

then reloaded systemd's configuration (`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`) and restarted rsync (`sudo systemctl restart rsync`).  This gave me the following:

```
$ ps -lfp $(pidof rsync)
F S UID        PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S root     18762     1  0  90  10 -  2785 -      13:43 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach
```

I now have a nice value of 10 like I wanted, but I don't think this will survive the next time I install an update to rsync.  Depending on your distribution you might have success with simply changing the values in /etc/default/rsync, but be sure to check the running process after restarting the daemon.

Comment: Oh systemd how I hate thee, let me count the ways. Talk about reinventing the wheel and making it square.

Answer (score 1):

Use `--rsync-path` option to run any wrapper or combination of commands (including `sudo`, `nice` and more) instead of basic `rsync` on remote side.

Comment: It's my understanding that `--rsync-path` only works when rsync is running over ssh and not when using rsyncd.